# Android Opentok SDK 2.0, Subscriber and publisher audio

Tags: android, opentok

I am developing android video chat application and  able to create video chat using opentok but audio from subscriber and publisher is too low. After connecting head phones to the devices able to hear voice. But without head phone not able to hear.

If any one knows, please give your valuable comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenTok Android is still in beta, which means that with each iteration bugs will be fixed. Check out the [new Android Beta](http://www.tokbox.com/blog/opentok-android-sdk-2-0-beta-2-is-released/) released a few days ago.